# Growing menu with scrollbar

Tags: unity-game-engine

I hate to ask such a generic question but I'm really stuck and super hoping someone can help me along the way. Here is the situation:

I'm making the GUI for a mobile app, portrait mode. I'm using canvas scalers to scale my canvasses with a reference width of 1080. This means I effectively don't know the height of my screen space.

What I want to create is a menu with a variable amount of items. The menu must be anchored to the bottom (with an offset margin) and grow upwards. So far I've been able to manage this using VerticalLayoutGroup and anchoring the rect transform to the bottom.

But my last requirement is that if the content would grow too big, a scrollbar would appear. The definition of the content being too big is: if it would extend the (unknown) screen height ( minus the offset margin of course). I hope the following image illustrates this much clearer:

[image]

I have a unity project here: https://ufile.io/v31br

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer Dave posted was close, but the problem is that the scrollview doesn't expand. I fixed it eventually by stretching the scrollview and resizing the parent manually as items are added. I set the anchors to the maximum size and adjust the `sizeDelta`.

```
public class MenuScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int MenuItemCount;
    public GameObject MenuItemPrefab;
    public Transform MenuItemParent;

    private RectTransform _rectTransform;

    void Start()
    {
        _rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        for (var i = 0; i <= MenuItemCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject instance = Instantiate(MenuItemPrefab, MenuItemParent, false);
            instance.GetComponent<Text>().text = instance.name = "Item " + i;

            float size = instance.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y;
            TryExpandBy(size + 10);
        }

    }

           private void TryExpandBy(float size)
        {
            var deltaY = _rectTransform.sizeDelta.y + size;
            if (deltaY > 0) deltaY = 0;
            _rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(_rectTransform.sizeDelta.x, deltaY);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a try to scrollView? here it is: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/scroll-view

You can use your vertical layout inside it and you will probably want to deactivate horizontal scroll and delete the horizontal slider.

Via script you can check its rectTransform height and compare it to your container's size, when reached maxHeight you can start managing your item's sizes

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the `ScrollRect` component as it is the right component to use in your case.

You can check the screen height with the `Screen.height` property.

Once you know the screen height you can compare it with your rect height and toggle the scrollbar with the `ScrollRect.vertical` property. You may have to change the `ScrollRect.verticalScrollbarVisibility` to `permanent` in order to make it work for you.